# How to multiply a value by a random range of values in R

Tags: r

Suppose i have some values, there it `dat$x1`=`c(23L, 45L)`.  How to multiply each of these values by randomly on any value that is in the range from -2 to 2? For example `23*1,5` or `23*-0,2` and so on.
What easy way to do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

We can also use

```r
dat$x1 * runif(nrow(dat), -2, 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use

```
s1 <- sample(seq(-2, 2, by = 0.1), nrow(dat), replace = FALSE)
dat$x1 * s1
```